# Duplicate Sharepoint List and OneDrive in the browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, onedrive, browsers, windows10

Duplicate sharepoint list and OneDrive in the browser

can you help us please with the steps how can we delete it from the  browser ?

thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same erroneous performance from OneDrive, a while back.
It was only about the Users OneDrive, i hadnt synced the company's sharepoint folder.

Since all of the data are in the cloud and the sync status was green, the steps that i performed were the below:

1. cut off one drive sync, from one drive settings and quit the client.
2. make a change on a test file and see that it was not sent to the user's OneDrive folder(online).
3. back up the remaining connections that OneDrive left.
4. delete folder locations, that showed up as duplicates.
5. sync OneDrive anew.
6. make sure everything's all right.
7. delete the backups

After the above, onedrive created the basic folders and had synced correctly.

Just a note, in my case we had Open on demand enabled, so most of the file structured was not even present in the users PC.

Comment: i did that but the problem when i

Comment: Sorry mate, but you didn't finish your sentence